# "Error running second Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"

Tags: android, android-activity

I can't seem to launch my application. It gives me an error like this: `Error running second Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter`.  Is there anything wrong with my manifest?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bill.myapplication1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bill.myapplication1.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Why have you set exported=true for your primary activity. This doesn't look like a receiver as you dont have any intent filters for receiver in manifest. Do you intent to open your app for other apps to interact?

Comment: 對不起，我只是找出另一個答案。我想我失去了，但我錯了。

Answer (score 0):

look there ,"android:exported="true">>", there is two ">"

Answer (score 0):

**change this in your manifest file**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.bill.myapplication1.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.bill.myapplication1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">>
```

You have double > near exported = "true"

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bill.myapplication1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bill.myapplication1.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
</application>
```